# Why can't herouku connect to my mongodb atlas database and retrieve data(works fine locally)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have spent one full day trying to sort this problem. Even now I have not found where is the problem. 
I have put proces.env.MONGODB_URI in both the server.js as well as in herouku config files. My website works perfectly on localhost:5000 but when I deploy it ,it refuses to connect with the database. 
xhr.js:178 GET http://jobproject2020.herokuapp.com/users 404 (Not Found)
This is the error I get when trying to get users from the database.
Below are my server.js files and other things

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
    // add other server routes to path array
    app.use(proxy(['/api' ], { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
} 

//serve static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
{
    //set static folder
    app.use(express.static('backend/build'));

    app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'backend','build','index.html'));
    });
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})


const userRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users',userRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
 [enter image description here][1]
```

and userlist file where I am requesting to database using axios

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Spring } from 'react-spring/renderprops';

import axios from 'axios';
import './stylecomp.css';


const User = props => (

<tr className="shadow p-2 mb-3 hvr-grow">
        <td className="font-weight-bold roww ">{props.user.username}</td>
        <td className="font-weight-bold roww">{props.user.address}</td>
        <td className="font-weight-bold roww">{props.user.phoneno}</td>
        <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/"+props.user._id}><button className="btn btn-primary"><i className="fas fa-user-edit"></i>

</button></Link>  |  <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>{ props.deleteuser(props.user._id)}}><i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </td>
</tr>

)

export default class UsersList extends Component {


    constructor(props){
         super(props);

         this.deleteuser = this.deleteuser.bind(this);

         this.state = {
             users:[]
         }

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/users')
        .then(response=>{
            this.setState({
                users:response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
    deleteuser(id)
    {   


        axios.delete('users/'+id)
        .then(res=>{console.log(res.data)});

        this.setState({
            users:this.state.users.filter(el=>el._id!== id)
        })

    }
    UsersList() {
        return this.state.users.map(currentuser=>{
            return <User user={currentuser} deleteuser={this.deleteuser} handleclick={this.handleclick} key={currentuser._id} classn={"rowdata"}/>
        })
    }
    render() 
    {
        return (


        <Spring from= {{opacity:0,marginTop:-500}} 
            to= {{opacity:1,marginTop:0}} 
            >
              {props =>(
                <div style={props}>
                    <div>


                <div className="container ">

              <h2>User List</h2>
              <table className="table">
                  <thead className="thead-light heading" >
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Address</th>
                          <th>Phoneno</th>
                          <th>Actions</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

            {this.UsersList()}
            </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </Spring>



        );
    }
}
```

I tried changing the axios.get() links from axios(/test/users) to axios(/users) and various variations of it and none worked.
when axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users) worked only when server is locally hosted.

EDIT: my package.json files below
package.json files from backend

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.7"
  }
}
```

package.json files from react

```
{
  "name": "jobproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "hover.css": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix backend && npm run build --prefix backend"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hey show me your package.json file

Comment: Okay I will added the main doc , check it out

Comment: @PrakashKarena I did the edit

Comment: your frontend and backend works fine but you are getting error while calling your api right?

Comment: yea, my site works fine on localhost , bt it doesnt work on heroku

Comment: app.use(proxy(['/api' ], { target: 'http://localhost:5000' })); try to change your target server url in your server.js

Comment: change it to what ? herouku link  of my project?

Comment: http://jobproject2020.herokuapp.com

Comment: xhr.js:178 GET http://jobproject2020.herokuapp.com/users  this is what I am getting now

Comment: in localhost you are getting your users at http://localhost:500/api/users or /users ??

Comment: no,just localhost:5000/users

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Go to your  [MongoDB Atlas server](https://cloud.mongodb.com/) and choose your cluster
- In the security tab click Network access on sidebar
- Click on "Add IP Address" button
- Give the whitelist entry as 0.0.0.0/0

Now try restarting your heroku app